# Mapping to a user

Tags: apex

so I am trying to map a note that a user has entered to one's id. 
The errors I am getting

> Illegal assignment from `Map<Id,String>` to `Map<Id,MTX_Matrix_Note__c>`
>   DML requires SObject or SObject list type: `Map<Id,MTX_Matrix_Note__c>`
>
> Illegal conversion from `Map<Id,MTX_Matrix_Note__c>` to MTX_`Matrix_Note__c`

The note is not being added.

```
 public static MTX_Matrix_Note__c createNewNote(Id candidateId, String enteredNotes ){

        Map<Id, MTX_Matrix_Note__c> usernotes = new Map<Id, String>();

        for (MTX_Matrix_Note__c nt : [SELECT Id, CreatedById, CreatedBy.Name, CreatedDate, Note__c, Name 
                      FROM MTX_Matrix_Note__c WHERE Candidate__c =:candidateId])
        {
            usernotes.put(candidateId, new MTX_Matrix_Note__c( Candidate__c = candidateId,
            Note__c = enteredNotes) );
        }

        insert usernotes;
        return usernotes;
    }
```

Any changes to my code are welcome, I just want the correct note for each user.

Editing a note is so that a user can edit his or her notes

```
public static MTX_Matrix_Note__c editNewNote(Id candidateId, String editedentry )
    {

        Map<Id, MTX_Matrix_Note__c> originalNotes = new Map<Id, MTX_Matrix_Note__c>();

        for (MTX_Matrix_Note__c a : [Select Id, Note__c FROM MTX_Matrix_Note__c WHERE Candidate__c =:candidateId])
        {            
            if (a.Note__c != editedentry){
                originalNotes.put(candidateId, 
                                  new MTX_Matrix_Note__c( Candidate__c = candidateId,
                                                                      Note__c = editedentry));
                }
            }
        insert originalNotes.values();

        return originalNotes.values();

    }
```

Comment: didnt you ask this same question earlier today?

Comment: yes I modified my code @glls

Comment: @glls I had changed my code a lot and got new errors, so i wasnt sure if i needed to make a new question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a typo. Instead of

```
Map<Id, MTX_Matrix_Note__c> usernotes = new Map<Id, String>();
```

write

```
Map<Id, MTX_Matrix_Note__c> usernotes = new Map<Id, MTX_Matrix_Note__c>();
```

You can perform DML operation only over SObject or SObject list
So instead of

```
insert usernotes;
```

use

```
insert usernotes.values();
```

If your method is going to return a map you should change its signature from

```
public static MTX_Matrix_Note__c createNewNote(Id candidateId, String enteredNotes)
```

to

```
public static Map<Id, MTX_Matrix_Note__c> createNewNote(Id candidateId, String enteredNotes)
```

Comment: Thank you, I had just changed my code and overlooked the Map<Id, MTX_Matrix_Note__c> usernotes = new Map<Id, MTX_Matrix_Note__c>();
and ty the insert usernotes.values(); worked, I never heard of a Sobject, I'll read up on it.

Comment: You're welcome)

Comment: One more question, does the second function make sense editNewNote, I constructed it based off of the first function. The goal is that if a user edits a note that was previously created, the edited note will replace the old one? Does my if statement suffice ?

Comment: No, if you return originalNotes.values() you should change the method signature from MTX_Matrix_Note__c to List<MTX_Matrix_Note__c> because originalNotes.values() method returns a List.

Comment: Does List<MTX_Matrix_Note__c> need to be change everywhere MTX_Matrix_Note__c is ? I understand why you said change the method signature to MTX_Matrix_Note__c bc originalNotes.values() method returns a List., but I don't understand where else it should be changed if editedentry is just a string.

Comment: No, if your method returns something the method signature must be relevant. So as map values() method returns a List<T> you should specify the correct relevant return type in the method signature.

Comment: Hey, thank you for bearing with me, I modified, and I thought the change you suggested was giving me an error, but it is because I forgot to save and refresh... I'm going to take my eyes off of code for a while lol

Comment: You`re welcome. But I strongly recommend you to read the apex docs.